# servlet automatically redirecting to localhost

Tags: servlets, redirect, localhost

i am hosting a website on my laptop from my home
i am using html/servlets along with apache tomcat
i've setup tomcat to host a virtual server by modifying the server.xml file and creating the ROOT.xml file in my project directory in the catalina folder
i've also forwarded the port 8080 on my laptop in my routers settings

heres the problem:
whenever i connect to my site using my global ip, i can get to the home page which is an html file just fine[image: Home page]

but when i put in the login and password and hit login, for some reason apache tries to locate the servlet file on the client machine (localhost) instead of the server machine
i've changed the all of the form actions and redirects to specify the global ip along with the appropriate servlet file but it still automatically gets changed to local host
[image: Auto Redirect]

because of this i am not able to access the rest of the site

can anybody help?

PS.i tried the site from my desktop which is on my network and also from another laptop which was on a different network but the same thing keeps happening

Thanks

Heres the code for my login servlet
the other servlets have similar database connections and redirects

```
//Log in check

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;

public class Login extends HttpServlet
{

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws IOException,      ServletException
{
PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
Connection con;
Statement s;
ResultSet rs;
ResultSet rs2;

try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://27.4.230.15:3306/irides","root",".hack%//sign66    ");
s=con.createStatement();
try{
String sap=req.getParameter("user");
rs=s.executeQuery("select passwd from participant where sap='"+sap+"'");
if(rs.next()){
if(rs.getObject(1).toString().equals(req.getParameter("passwd"))){
HttpSession ss=req.getSession();
ss.setAttribute("sap",sap);
rs2=s.executeQuery("select * from team where sap="+sap);
ss.setAttribute("team",rs2);
rs2=s.executeQuery("select pname,points from participant order by points desc limit 1,     10");
ss.setAttribute("lead",rs2);
ss.setAttribute("ctr",0);
res.sendRedirect("http://27.4.230.15:8080/irides/User");
}
else{
out.println("<html><body>Either the username or the password is incorrect. You will be     redirected to the login page shortly</body></html>");
res.sendRedirect("http://iridescence.in/incorrectPass.html");
}
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
out.println(e);
out.println("<html><body>A problem was encountered due to which the operation could not     be completed. Please go back to the login page and try again.</body></html>");
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
out.println(e);
}
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws IOException,     ServletException
{
doGet(req,res);
}

}
```

---

@ everyone....it was a real dumb mistake...i forgot to change the form action link on my homepage html file which was redirecting to the servlet and for some reason completely forgot about checking that file for the source of the error

Comment: Show us the relevant code.

Comment: nevermind i found the error....really stupid mistake on my part

Comment: check your web.xml if have any path value set to localhost . or else , I strongly agree with the answer below

Comment: would you mind to share the mistake , would be good for us to acknowledge

Comment: @ binoy dalal can u share us the mistake which u had found ?

Comment: it was a real dumb mistake...i forgot to change the form action link on my homepage html file which was redirecting to the servlet and for some reason completely forgot about checking that file for the source of the error

Answer (score 1):

According to me , i think you have been working and testing in the localhost..so in the coding side u have given the link to redirect localhost:8080/filename but you need to change the localhost link into respective server ip with repective directory depends on the server..i think u didnt change the localhost with file name..change that using serverip with the directory path of the server..hopefully it would help u im not sure